# KNIME: How to properly use Auto Binner

Tags: knime

I want to create 10 different Bins with a table I already have, But when I use it, some cells appear with the sign of [ ? ] instead of a bin, for example

```
RSI    RSI (BINNED)
58.82  (55.846,59.405]
68.43   ?
65.2    ?
72.18   ?
72.29   ?
71.69   ?
71.74   ?
57.01   (55.846,59.405]
54.004   (52.923,55.846]
```

With this output (RSI binned), I can imagine that there should be a last bin (from 65 to 100) and it's not creating it. Also, when I filter the output, I can see that there are 9 different correct bins, and a last that appears like empty (?). Anyone knows why?

Comment: How did you create the table? Maybe the range of values is not properly populated in the input table, so the bins do not match it.

Comment: In this example, I created the RSI column using the TA LIB function, so all the values are between 0 and 100 (because of the nature of RSI), so I don't think that would be the problem.

Comment: Also, in this precise example, the bins that were created by the Auto Binner are:
[4.158,35.115]
(35.115,40.579]
(40.579,44.244]
(44.244,47.284]
(47.284,50.101]
(50.101,52.923]
(52.923,55.846]
(55.846,59.405]
(59.405,64.663]

And I set in the Auto binner that there should be 10 bins, so as far as I know, there should be 1 more that would be (64.663,100]. So all the values that are in the last bin appear with the [ ? ] mark, the problem is that I don't know why the auto binner is not creating the last bin.

Comment: Have you checked its min-max values of the input column?

Comment: The Min value in the RSI column is: 4.15847.
The Max value is: 94.1414